# Windows XP environment variable for "local setting" folder

Tags: windows, windows-xp, environment-variables

There's an environment variable, %appdata%, equal to

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\
```

Is there a variable for either

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\
```

or

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For temporary changes you can use [set command](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) that can be used in scripts or in the command window.

More permanent changes can be made via the System properties dialog box by doing right-click on My Computer -> Properties and in the Advanced tab select Environment Variables. From there you can create new path variables to use.

There are also other ways to accomplish this task, see [more info here](http://vlaurie.com/computers2/Articles/environment.htm)

Answer (score 6):

This is very cryptical, but it works with standard Windows XP commands:

```
for /f "tokens=4,5 delims=\" %a in ('reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" /v "Local AppData"^|find "REG_SZ"') do set LocalAppData=%userprofile%\%a\%b
```

... and it is language independent (use %%a and %%b instead of %a and %b inside batch files).

Comment: You *did* spot the glaring *»Do not use this registry key«* message in there?

Comment: Where should I have seen that? Who said "Do not use this registry key" ?

Comment: @MehrdadMirreza: It is suggested to not access the registry for this, please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/03/55532.aspx for an explanation. - See as well: [How can I get the path of a Windows “special folder” for a specific user?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/198124/367456)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one by default, though you can type `set` into a command prompt to see a list of all environment variables on your system.

An alternative for you is to use `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings` and `%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\Application Data` or set your own environment variables with the `set` command.

Comment: Note that this depends on the language of the OS and thus is a very poor solution to the problem.

Comment: This is version-specific, and would not function on Windows Vista or Windows 7. %LOCALAPPDATA% Should work for them, though.

Comment: Darth Android, the question specified Windows XP. As for a language independent way of getting the path, Johannes' solution is indeed superior

Answer (score 3):

There isn't such a variable on legacy Windows versions. However, you can get the folder path through VBScript:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
WScript.Echo objShell.Namespace(&H1c&).Self.Path
```

You can then use this in a batch file as follows:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('cscript /nologo localappdata.vbs') DO (
  set LOCALAPPDATA=%%i
)
```

On current versions of Windows this variable (`%LOCALAPPDATA%`) exists by default.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly and should have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score -3):

Just use %appdata% windows xp --

and use the explorer window up-arrow to nav to the users directory, then select local settings.

takes a split second or two.  easy.

Comment: Its not clear for anyone how you want to help the others through your post.